# Mysql : Find sum of top 7 scores

Tags: sql, mysql

Consider user game play table having user_id, level and score. Requirement is to construct a Leaderboard with following conditions:

1. Player should have played at least 7 levels.
2. Rank is determined by taking 7 best scores summing them and sorting in descending order.

Player might have played 20 levels. We have to pick 7 levels in which he has best score ( EX: If he has scored more in lets say 3,4,5,7,8,9,10 then sum of that)

```
user_id   level  score
1           1      10
1           2       5
.......
```

I am started with below query

```
SELECT  user_id , ? as totalScore // I am not able to figure out how to pick and sum 7 best score
FROM user_game
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING count(level) > 7
ORDER BY totalScore DESC;
```

Note: I am using the 5.7 version mysql server and I think we cannot use the PARTITION BY clause in this version.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is 8 years old. You need to upgrade. Now.